Javascript Drag and drop children without triggering dragstart for parent
I have HTML like this
<details draggable="true" open="">
<summary>author</summary>
<div draggable="true">name</div>
<div draggable="true">company</div>
</details>

I want seperate "dragstart" event listeners for the divs and a third for the containing block when i start my cursor on summary.
Currently div.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {}) also fires the event for the parent when the child divs are dragged. I did try event.stopPropagation but that makes the drop stop working when i drop onto a rich text field (the dataTransfer data doesn't transfer).

It sounds like you have two event listeners. You can just use one event listener, listening on a parent element (Event delegation). The e.target will always be either the <details> or the <div>.
In this example I add a class name to the element being dragged. That way I know what the element in in the drop event callback function. And then depending on the nodeName you can decide what to do next. In the example I clone either the <details> or the <div> and append it on an appropriate element.


const list = document.querySelector('section.details');
const drop = document.querySelector('section.drop');

list.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.currentlydraged')
    .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('currentlydraged'));
  e.target.classList.add('currentlydraged');
});

drop.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

drop.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let item = document.querySelector('.currentlydraged');
  let detailsElm = e.target.closest('details');
  let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
  if(detailsElm && item.nodeName == 'DIV'){
    detailsElm.append(clone);
  }else if(item.nodeName == 'DETAILS'){
    let drop = e.target.closest('section.drop');
    drop.append(clone);
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('.currentlydraged')
    .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('currentlydraged'));
});
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

section.drop {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid thin black;
}
<section class="details">
  <details draggable="true" open="">
    <summary>author</summary>
    <div draggable="true">name</div>
    <div draggable="true">company</div>
  </details>
  <details draggable="true" open="">
    <summary>author</summary>
    <div draggable="true">name</div>
    <div draggable="true">company</div>
  </details>
</section>
<section class="drop">
</section>




You can try this approach:

Create a variable (global for listener functions) where you will track which event is called

When started child dragstart then set this variable to true

When started child dragend then set this variable to false


Here is complete code for basic situation:


const detailsContainer = document.querySelector('details');
const detailsList = detailsContainer.querySelectorAll('div');

let isChildEvent = false;

const parentDragStartListener = e => {
  if (isChildEvent) return;
  
  console.log('parent');
}

const childDragStartListener = () => {
  isChildEvent = true;
  
  console.log('child');
}

const childDragEndListener = () => {
  isChildEvent = false;
}

detailsContainer.addEventListener('dragstart', parentDragStartListener);

detailsList.forEach(detail => {
  detail.addEventListener('dragstart', childDragStartListener);
  detail.addEventListener('dragend', childDragEndListener);
});
<details draggable="true" open="">
  <summary>author</summary>
  <div draggable="true">name</div>
  <div draggable="true">company</div>
</details>



